How to fix mongosh v2.3.3 connection error with AWS DocumentDB v5.0.0
When I try to connect to documentdb cluster version 5.0.0 using mongosh version 2.3.3 it is returned the error message:
MongoServerError: Unsupported mechanism [ -301 ]
I am using the connection string with this format:
mongosh 'mongodb://my_user:my_password@my-host-name.cluster-id-aws.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/my_db_name&tls=true&tlsCAFile=rds-global-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false'

I tried to search for a solution at the AWS DocumentDB and MongoDB Community documentations, but I didn't find a fix for this issue.

Does this answer your question: How to connect to Amazon DocumentDB using a connection string?

Also got same issue recently and found this: https://repost.aws/questions/QUg7ZGj0m5R1OZWRJ9KiMYXQ/urgent-documentdb-connection-stopped-unexpectedly
just add authSource=admin to your URI parameters. admin database should hold auth credentials for users, unless you set different db name.
also a bit more about that parameter:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-iam-authentication-with-amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility/
